# How do I approach a probability problem where different probabilities apply to the same question?

Tags: probability

Suppose I am asking 3 people whether an object is type A or type B.  They each examine the object in a different way and compare it with their past data.

Person 1 says "Of all the objects I've examined that were like this one, 60% were type A and 40% were type B"

Person 2 says "Of all the objects I've examined that were like this one, 70% were type A and 30% were type B"

Person 3 says "Of all the objects I've examined that were like this one, 80% were type A and 20% were type B"

How would I use their information to find the probabilities that it's type A or B?

Comment: Is this an actual course/exam question, or a hypothetical question?

Comment: I'm applying it to business.  I have several lines of data with different attributes and I'm trying to come up with a probabilistic way of classifying a new line of data.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention you have streams of data, I'm going to assume you have access not just to the probabilities they report, but also the number of times they've encountered such an object (and therefore also the number that turned out to be each object type).  If you don't, just skip to the end of the answer, I also consider the case where you don't.

One way would be to reason as follows: for an object like yours, there is a true probability $p$ that it is type $A$, and probability $1-p$ it is type $B$.

Now, each individual $A,B,C$ has observed $N_1,N_2,N_3$ objects and concluded that 
$n_1,n_2,n_3$ were actually type $A$. In your example, we have

$$\frac{n_1}{N_1}= 0.6$$$$\frac{n_2}{N_2}=0.7$$$$\frac{n_3}{N_3}=0.8$$

If you have studied elementary statistics, you will recognise that under mild assumptions, each $n_i \sim Binomial(N_i, p)$

It follows that $n= n_1 + n_2 + n_3$ is also Binomial with parameters $Binomial(N_1+N_2+N_3,p)$.

It immediately follows by the strong law of large numbers that

$$\frac{n_1 + n_2 + n_3}{N_1 + N_2 + N_3} \to p$$

almost surely (ie. with probability $1$). Hence you can use all of the reported successes together to obtain a stronger estimate together.

Now, suppose you **only** have access to the probabilities each of them reports: $p_1, p_2, p_3$. Well the above theorem also holds for each individual $p$, so that

$$p_i \to p$$

almost surely for $i=1,2,3$. Hence by something called Slutsky's theorem it follows that

$$p_1 + p_2 + p_3 \to 3p$$

and hence

$$\frac{p_1 + p_2 + p_3}{3} \to p$$

converges in probability. So if you don't have access to the original trials/successes in your data stream, you can also just average the three probabilities and know that your average will converge in probability to  the true value of $p$, assuming binomial assumptions hold (constant $p$, independent trials).

Comment: I tried confirming this experimentally.  I have about 13000 rows of data. I chose 3 columns that had 1-or-0 data.  (One was the classification). I calculated the (X% for 0), (Y% for 1) chance of each and then averaged them over the two columns. There were 4 possible probabilities, so I grouped the data by these and checked how accurate they were.  It turned out reasonable for probabilities close to 50% but badly for smaller ones.  For instance, a predicted 16% chance of type 1 was actually 5% in reality and a predicted 30% chance was 9%.  I can't disprove your answer but something seems off.

Comment: This was on an automatically-calculating spreadsheet, so I dropped in a number of different data columns and it always turned out that the small probabilities were larger than the real result.  I'm going to ask this as a different question because not knowing the probabilities of other types might be hurting the answer.